# How to get text content inside quotation marks from text file using cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, cmd

I have a text file with content like below and it has only one line.

```
{"audioInputs":0,"audioOutputs":1,"enable":true,"uid":"b350cbfe366340b6a6a0722806e9d90fc0645aa75f894491b8cbba2a17","videoInputs":0},"mobile":{"device_scale_factor":1.00000001,"enable":false,"height":1024,"width":1280},"name":"G0099","navigator":{"max_touch_points":0,"platform":"Win32"},"plugins":{"all_enable":true,"flash_enable":true},"profile_id":"645ce0c7e2d559bd618e7a3e","proxy":{"password":"","username":""}
```

I need to get the specified text as below and print it to another text file

`G0099`

Comment: This is not just any text file, this is a JSON file. I would strongly advise against attempting to parse a JSON file using `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "json={"audioInputs":0,"audioOutputs":1,"enable":true,"uid":"b350cbfe366340b6a6a0722806e9d90fc0645aa75f894491b8cbba2a17","videoInputs":0},"mobile":{"device_scale_factor":1.00000001,"enable":false,"height":1024,"width":1280},"name":"G0099","navigator":{"max_touch_points":0,"platform":"Win32"},"plugins":{"all_enable":true,"flash_enable":true},"profile_id":"645ce0c7e2d559bd618e7a3e","proxy":{"password":"","username":""}"
SET "grabnext="
FOR %%e IN (%json::=,%) DO IF DEFINED grabnext (SET "grabnext=%%~e"&GOTO done) ELSE IF "%%~e"=="name" SET "grabnext=y"
ECHO NOT found
GOTO :eof

:done
ECHO data retrieved:%grabnext%

GOTO :EOF
```